# How to `update` new value choosing from `select box` on click save button?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to `update` new value choosing from `select box` on click save button.

I am using ng-click function like this in my JS function for update button:

```
   $scope.updateDealDetail = function updateDealDetail (){
      $scope.showEditView = !$scope.showEditView;
      $scope.dealDetail.decisionMakerDetail.email = $scope.selectedid;
   }
```

My function for edit button:

```
$scope.editUserDetail = function editUserDetail(){
        $scope.showEditView = !$scope.showEditView;
        $scope.showSubmitView = !$scope.showSubmitView;
        deal.getIdData($scope.accountDetail. accountUsers[0].role,$scope.accountDetail.id).then(function successCb(data){
          $scope.editIdOptionsData=data;
          $scope.selectedid = $scope.editIdOptionsData[0].email;
      });
    };
```

and my HTML for bitton click is like this :

```
<select ng-model="selectedid" class="form-control">
   <option ng-selected="selectedid" ng-repeat="eiod in editIdOptionsData" value="{{eiod.email}}">{{eiod.email}}
```

```
<button ng-click="updateDealDetail(eoid.email)" ng-disabled="dealDataSaveButtonDisabled">Update</button>
```

I am trying to this through ng-repeat because of by using ng-options my data through API is now showing in the box. But My data which is on first index is only getting set. What to do to set the a default value for the selection box and by selection any value, onclick need to update that value.

Comment: please describe `my value is not updating` - what is the expected result? Also add more parts like the `getDeal()` function and the view code

Comment: The value which I select that is not getting saved.

Comment: Please provide information about  $scope.dealDetail object.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use ngRepeat to render options, this is your problem. Correct code would be:

```
<select class="form-control" 
        ng-model="selectedid" 
        ng-options="eiod.email as eiod.email for eiod in editIdOptionsData">
</select>
```

Comment: what is the problem with ngRepeat ?

Comment: Incorrect model binding (can't bind to objects). ngRepeat is not supposed to be used to render select options.

Comment: Hey can you please explain too. what is need to write "eiod.email as eiod.email for eiod in editIdOptionsData" like this?

Comment: @VishakhaNehe select and options forms a single control.  So consider using the angular ng-options

Comment: `eiod.email as eiod.email for eiod in editIdOptionsData` means: iterate over `editIdOptionsData` and with each iteration item `eiod` render option's label (text) using `eiod.email` and value `eiod.email` again. value as label for item in array.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice to use `ng-options`, `ng-model` and `ng-change` on the `<select>` element

**Online demo - https://plnkr.co/edit/Gaa8sMgerRv6chio4iYa?p=preview**

html

```
<select 
    ng-model="selectedItem" 
    ng-change="onSelectedItemChanged()"
    ng-options="item as item.email for item in items"></select>
```

js

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{
    email: 'asd1@asd.com'
  }, {
    email: 'asd2@asd.com'
  }];

  $scope.selectedItem = $scope.items[0];

  $scope.onSelectedItemChanged = function() {
    alert('you changed it to ' + $scope.selectedItem.email);
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you edit your code in which there is a button and on click that button I could save my email id which is get selected please... It would be very helpful to me.